# Join two LINQ expressions together

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Given:

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2>> x = ...;   // an example might be: a => a.DailyEmail
Expression<Func<T2, bool>> y = ...; // an example might be: a => a.Last < DateTime.Now
```

Where `x` contains **only** a member reference whereas `y` may contain any expression, what would be the best way to join the two together so that I get a new `Expression<Func<T1, bool>>` that contains the member reference from `x` to obtain a `T2` and then the expression from `y` that turns that `T2` into a bool?

**Note**: I need an *expression* as the result, **not** the actual variable. Thus I cannot compile the two expressions individually and call them both against a known `T1`.

Comment: [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) could not help you to join both expressions?

Comment: Predicate builder works to join expressions with And or Or.